# Svelte/Sapper Build - Seemingly old CSS still exists after building?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, svelte, sapper

I just committed and pushed a minor CSS tweak. On my server I `git pull`, `npm run build`, and `forever restart __sapper__/build`

Now there seems to be more than one version of the same CSS rule across different files, as per the below screenshot (this is after disabling browser cache):

[image: invalid CSS rules]

The correct rule is the third one (`vertical-align: top; margin-top: 1px;`), which seems to be a combination of CSS files.

Any idea where the 'old' rules are coming from? Cached somewhere somehow?

/EDIT This is my `rollup.config.js`: https://gist.github.com/Bandit/bbcfd6c70ace5800765313dfe6021854

/EDIT2 The styles in question are in a `/style/global.scss` file, which is included using the following code in `/routes/_layout.svelte`:

```css
<style lang="scss" global>
    @import "./style/global.scss";
    main {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 5rem 1rem 0 1rem;
    }
</style>
```

Guessing this is somehow the issue? Where is the right place to 'inject' global stylesheet for colours/theme/typography etc?

/EDIT3 The styles being included via `_layout.svelte` are being included more than once in dev as well, here's a screenshot:

[image: duplicated CSS rules]

Answer (score 1):

These selectors don't seem to come from a Svelte component, since they're not scoped (e.g. `.split-button.svelte-a9ylb1`)? Or are you using `:global(.split-button)` in a Svelte component?

Anyway... I failed to reproduce your issue, but my intuition is that your problem probably comes from the `postcss` plugin. It has an [`inject` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss#inject) that is enabled by default. What this option does is injecting a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your doc; the code that does this is appended to your modules' JS by the `postcss` plugin. This behaviour might very well clash with what `svelte-preprocess` or `rollup-plugin-svelte` is doing.

Try adding `inject: false` in the 3 places where you're using `postcss` in your Rollup config, and see if this helps.

Another possibility might be the service worker. I don't think an issue there could produce your result you get, but we never know... You should try options like "Update on reload" and "Bypass for network" (I don't know what are the equivalent options in your browser) to see if that makes a difference.

Otherwise, you may have to show more of your code. Where does this precise CSS rule come from (e.g. style tag in a Svelte component, SCSS file in node_modules, ...)? How is it imported into your project (e.g. `import './app.css'`, `@import './app.scss'`, etc.), and where? Also, I'm surprised that you have the `postcss` rollup plugin only in the server (the one that is not registered in `sveltePreprocess`)... What do you need this for, that you don't need on the client?

**EDIT: Follow up**

Wait, what? You've got some style files under your `routes` directory?? `routes/style/global.scss`?

Even with that, I don't appear to be able to reproduce your problem, but it's worth noting that Sapper will try to include *every file* it encounters under this directory. If you've got a plugin that lets you import `*.scss` files, then Sapper will actually see a `global.scss.js`, so it will think it's a server route. Without a plugin that can eat SCSS, it should... crash. If the plugin in question is `postcss` with its default `inject` option still to `true`, to me it looks like a star suspect...

Anyway, some further points of clarification...

`svelte-preprocess` enables `lang="xxx"`, `global` attribute in `<style global ...>`, *in `.svelte` files only*.

`rollup-plugin-postcss` can additionally be added, directly in `plugins` array (i.e. not as an option of `svelte` plugin). It gives support for `import './foo.scss'`, in `.js` files, as well as in the `<script>` part of `.svelte` files.

(Of course, SASS support by PostCSS, or PostCSS support by Svelte preprocess are depending on the config you feed them.)

OK. So now there are multiple places where some CSS / SCSS can enter your build. That I can think of, there are the following ways:

- `<link rel='stylesheet' href='global.css'>` in `src/template.html`: this one will copied as is without processing.
- I suppose you can also have such a "custom" `<link>` tag in the markup (~HTML) part of a `.svelte` file, and it would be included as is in the resulting HTML (you'd still have the responsibility that the reference CSS file be accessible at the given URL).
- `import 'something.css'` or 'import 'something.scss'`in a`.js`or JS part of a`.svelte`file: these will get processed by bundler & plugins, and converted to some JS code, with optionally additional assets that the JS can reference (typically, a proper CSS file is generated, and some JS code dynamically injects a``tag for it at runtime; another approach is to generate some JS that will inject every CSS rule in the doc). PostCSS with`inject: true` uses the CSS + inject tag method.
- the CSS / SCSS style that you write in the `<style>` part of a `.svelte` file will also be processed by the Svelte plugin in a similar way as described just before (`preprocess` option required to accept anything else than raw CSS); depending on the plugin configuration, it may also try to write a '.css' file for your application (see [docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte#extracting-css). With the `emitCss` option, that is apparently needed for Sapper, it should output one CSS file per component (or maybe entrypoint).

In your case, you say that you've removed `rollup-plugin-postcss` from your config, so the 3rd point (import css from js) should not be possible anymore.

Well... I just hope this can help you investigate further.

I've pushed a Sapper + PostCSS example on a branch on [this repo](https://github.com/rixo/playground-sapper). As far as I can tell, it doesn't have the issue you're describing here. So maybe you can find the problem by comparing with what you have. See [this commit](https://github.com/rixo/playground-sapper/commit/95e2363ea8d74cc3af41f3eb585066aa775ab94f) for the diff with the vanilla official template.

I tried to also add `rollup-plugin-postcss`, like you initially had in your config, in order to be able to import `.scss` from outside of Svelte components. But I failed to find a way to do this that don't conflict with Sapper.

**EDIT 2**

Oh, and just to be sure... Be sure to try a little `rm -r __sapper__ && rm -r src/node_modules/@sapper` (notice: `node_modules` under `src`, not the one in your project's root) before pursuing your investigation. I'm sure you've already done that, but better safe than sorry. Stale things can live in there.

Comment: I have just followed a jumbled mix of guides to set up SCSS since (at the time I started) there was no official guidance on setting it up, so that likely explains why I have redundant and/or unnecessary calls. Will play with a few things in a few hours based on your information and reply back :)

Comment: I've completely commented out all `postcss` related stuff in `rollup.config.js` and my SCSS still works, so I guess it was redundant. I still see a `main.css` and an `app.css` in my `<head>` though, and both seem to contain the same CSS - so I guess this is something to do with how I'm including my "global" CSS? Will add some extra info to the original question.

Comment: Did you also add `inject: false` to the `postcss` in your `preprocess`?

Comment: Ok so just `npm uninstall rollup-plugin-postcss` and it broke the site due to my usage of the 'global' attribute in `_layout.svelte` which apparently requires postcss to work - so guessing this is the culprit. Thing is if I don't use that `global` attribute functionality of `svelte-preprocess` then what's the best way to include global theme CSS?

Comment: Actually even with `global` removed from that call and my `global.scss` import commented out, I still get `app.css` and `main.css` which have all the same selectors.............

Comment: Thanks so much for the further debug guidance - this one is really stumping me. I spent quite a few hours last night trying different combinations of approaches but for the life of me can't work out where `main.css` and `app.css` are actually coming from. I dug into the `svelte-preprocess` code a bit and think there's a chance that the `node-sass render` call is the one generating one of those files, while Svelte itself is generating the other - but this is all guess work right now. Maybe I'll try reproducing the issue in a fresh repo and work backwards.

Comment: Regarding the 'styles in the routes directory' comment you made - no, my styles are in `src/style/`, but (from memory) the Sass parser needed the directory relative to the base? I'll try putting `@import "../style/global.scss"` and see what happens :) I also don't import any CSS within script tags currently.

Comment: To me `@import "./style/global.scss";` from `/routes/_layout.svelte` seemed to indicate that your `style` folder was under `/routes`. Not sure about that, actually. But on my machine, it causes a crash. So that's probably not your problem. And yes, `main.[hash].css` is produced by Sapper. Not `app.css` though. Unless you've got a chunk named `app`... An `app.svelte` route, maybe?

Comment: I don't have an `app.svelte` - I think that one is coming from one of the packages somewhere. Annoyingly there's no way that I can see to determine the generation source of these CSS files. Anyway I've spent way too many hours on this now so I'm giving up and moving my global styles to a self-compiled static CSS file in `/static`... lame. Really need official documentation on best way to attach global/theme CSS in Sapper.